# почему под суперюзером не смогу адекватно отлавливать ошибки и в ходе использования ПО c ssh-клиента

Tags: c#, linux, сервер, debian, ssh

Есть программа подключается по ssh к ssh-серверу и заходит на сервер под чёткой супер пользователя.

НО почему-то выдает :

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/testssh: No such file or directory

su: must be run from a terminal
```

Не могу понять почему так, почему команды в терминале "от руки" выполняются, а в программе "через код" нет (программа работает на ssh-клиенте ).

*Если через SSH так и будут ошибки в ответ приходить, не смотря на то что все работает и данные принимаются, я не смогу адекватно отработать это в коде, потому что не смогу адекватно отлавливать ошибки и в ходе использования ПО смотреть где на каком этапе произошел сбой, толи устройство отвалилось, толи связь, толи ПО глючит. Поэтому тут нужна четкая работа программы: запрос-корректный ответ.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *почему под суперюзером не выдоит...* - кто кого доит? :)

Comment: @vikttur ниплоха ниплоха :3

Comment: а что говорят логи на сервере, когда вы пытаетесь выполнять команды через программу?

Comment: @МаксЖуков вывод программы добавил

Comment: @timob256, посмотрите https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195950/executing-command-as-su